Novel where robots look human and commit suicide if they realize they aren't human
The plot line I remember is that most or many people aren't actually human, but ultra realistic robots who look exactly like humans. No-one in the story really knows if they are a human or a robot, and all assume themselves to be human. If a robot discovers they aren't human -- for example, one scene involved surviving a fall down a mine shaft that would have killed a human -- they almost always immediately commit suicide, because they can't take the knowledge that they spent their whole life thinking they were human, but they were really just a robot all this time.

In roughly which year did you read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?

If you've lost access to the account you used to post this question, please merge your new account with your previous one by following the instructions provided here. Once the accounts are merged, you'll regain the ability to edit this question without approval from other users, post comments within this thread, and mark an answer as accepted, if you wish to do so.

see if anything here rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/RidiculouslyHumanRobots/Literature
